# Swagger API breaks when Route attribute is set to Controller Action - ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1. In My Web Application I have integrated swagger. Which works fine, shows the endpoints properly in the swagger API documentation. The code in startup is as below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
            services.AddSwaggerGen( c => {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
            });
}

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Clients}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Push Notification API V1");
            });

         }
```

To my Error Controller I just added a HttpStatusCodeHandler method and gave a route as below.
Then the swagger gives a error as:

> "Failed to load API definition." Fetch error undefined
>   /swagger/v1/swagger.json

The method code is as follows.

```
[Route("Error/Error/{statusCode}")]
public IActionResult HttpStatusCodeHandler(int statusCode)
{
    switch (statusCode)
    {
        case 404:
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Sorry, the resource you requested could not be found.";
            break;
    }
    return View("Error");
}
```

Every time I comment out the Route attribute `[Route("Error/Error/{statusCode}")]` the swagger API works fine. What could be the error in this?

Comment: Have you tried using the specific HTTP method attribute instead of the generic Route ? If your controller action should be mapped to accept GET method requests, use the `[HttpGet("Error/Error/{statusCode}")]` attribute.

Comment: Can you provide a minimum, reproducible example

Comment: @jandrew if i make it HttpGet the error in the swagger goes away. But the Error Action appears in the Swagger API

Comment: @sm101 Can clarify what you mean by "Error Action appears in the Swagger API" ? Are you getting another exception ?

Comment: @jandrew No What i meant was that if I make the method "HttpStatusCodeHandler()" actions, method attribute as HttpGet instead of Route, then in the Swagger API documentation which swagger generates, the Method gets exposed as an GET Endpoint.

Comment: The method has to be one of the specific HTTP request types. It just documents that the allowed method is GET. It has to be defined one way or another. You can reference the Swagger docs if you want to exclude it but you can't define it with just `Route` because it has to know what HTTP verb is allowed. From the code you posted, It looks like it is indeed a GET endpoint. I don't see a problem with documenting that.

Answer (score 2):

The root cause is your controller is recognized as ApiController if you add `Route` attribute, and swagger will be broken if you do not add `HttpMethod` attribute in your controller.

Add `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]` attribute to your controller, and the swagger broken problem should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `[Route("Error/Error/{statusCode}")]` from the method and included the middleware `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects()` in the configure method.

I am not sure on the exact reason for the swagger API error.